# vue JS component import without webpack

Tags: vue.js, flask

I am building a flask app and jinja2 template. So I am planning to use Vue functionality asn per my requiremnt and not planning for single page app.

I am trying to use vue-carousel but not able to import it.

here is my html code for index.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--Import materialize.css-->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
        href="{{ url_for('static', filename='node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css')}}"
        media="screen,projection" />
    <!--Import custom css-->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
        href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/landing-page-style.css')}}" />
    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>

<body>
    <header class="landing-page-header">
        <div class="primary-overlay">
            <!--Nav Bar-->
            <div class="navbar-fixed">
                <nav class="transparent">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="nav-wrapper">
                            <a href="#home" class="brand-logo">artext</a>
                            <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-nav" class="button-collapse">
                                <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#home" id="login"><i class="small material-icons left">login</i>Login</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#home"><i class="medium material-icons left">how_to_reg</i>Register</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#home" id="home"><i class="medium material-icons left">home</i>Home</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <!--Side Nav-->
            <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="#home"><i class="material-icons left">login</i>Login</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#home"><i class="material-icons left">how_to_reg</i>Register</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#home"><i class="material-icons left">home</i>Home</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div id="app">
                <carousel :data="data"></carousel>
            </div>
            <section class="slider" id="slider">
                <ul class="slides transparent">
                    <li>
                        <div class="caption center-align">
                            <h2>Take Your Dream Vacation</h2>
                            <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3 hide-on-small-only">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                                consectetur
                                adipisicing elit. Veniam non illo earum cumque id est!</h5>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-large">Learn More</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="caption left-align">
                            <h2>We Work With All Budgets</h2>
                            <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3 hide-on-small-only">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                                consectetur
                                adipisicing elit. Veniam non illo earum cumque id est!</h5>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-large">Learn More</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="caption right-align">
                            <h2>Group & Individual Getaways</h2>
                            <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3 hide-on-small-only">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                                consectetur
                                adipisicing elit. Veniam non illo earum cumque id est!</h5>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-large">Learn More</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </section>
        </div>
    </header>
    <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="{{ url_for('static', filename='node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
    <!--Import materialize.js-->
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="{{ url_for('static', filename='node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js')}}"></script>
  
    <!--Import app-custom.js-->
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/landing-page-js.js')}}"></script>
    <!--Import vue.js-->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='node_modules/vue-carousel/dist/vue-carousel.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script type="module">
        import Carousel from '/static/node_modules/vue-carousel/src/Carousel.vue';
        var app = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
            data() {
                return {
                    data: [
                        '<div class="example-slide">Slide 1</div>',
                        '<div class="example-slide">Slide 2</div>',
                        '<div class="example-slide">Slide 3</div>',
                    ],
                }
            },
        })
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I am using npm to install the component. inside static folder I am keeping all the module.

While running the app getting the following error.

```
Loading module from “http://127.0.0.1:6009/static/node_modules/vue-carousel/src/Carousel.vue” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“application/octet-stream”).
```

any help appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think JavaScript module is only allow a JavaScript MIME type such as `text/javascript` that's why your vue file is blocked. See the note section from [JavaScript modules](https://v8.dev/features/modules#mjs).

You can try to load another file such as index.js or manually set the `Content-Type` header. The error should be gone but you might face another error.

You cannot just import vue file because it's not normal JavaScript file. The vue file must be parsed by Webpack (Vue Loader) which will produce multiple JavaScript files.

So if you don't want to use Webpack then you have to use files (already parsed/build) in the dist directory (may differ in other packages) or from CDN such as [unpkg.com](https://unpkg.com/) or [jsdelivr](https://www.jsdelivr.com/).

You can see how to use with CDN from their [examples](https://ssense.github.io/vue-carousel/examples/). See the resources section in JSFiddle.

Comment: I want to us use Vue insteed of jQuery

Comment: @SubhananGanguli I'm not talking about any jQuery.

Comment: I am not looking for SPA. I want to us Vue insteed of jQuery in my app page.but here I am having issue to import.

Comment: @SubhananGanguli I also didn't talking about SPA. Have you read my answer yet?

Comment: Of course I read your post. As I am using jinja 2 template I want it as per requirment. Also I tried to point dist folder but its unable to identify the component. you can check the html code here

Comment: @SubhananGanguli My answer explains why you unable to load your vue file and how to do it with alternative methods. For about your vue code you should look at their example in JSFiddle such as https://jsfiddle.net/quinnssense/bojn4dz4/2/. Try to make it works from simple example first. If you still have a problem you can create a new question to ask specifically or let me know here.